# Iterative union of multiple dataframes in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to concatenate multiple dataframes using `unionAll` function in pyspark.

This is what I do :

```
df_list = []

for i in range(something):
    normalizer = Normalizer(inputCol="features", outputCol="norm", p=1)
    norm_df = normalizer.transform(some_df)
    norm_df = norm_df.repartition(320)
    data = index_df(norm_df)
    data.persist()
    mat = IndexedRowMatrix(
        data.select("id", "norm")\
            .rdd.map(lambda row: IndexedRow(row.id, row.norm.toArray()))).toBlockMatrix()
    dot = mat.multiply(mat.transpose())
    df = dot.toIndexedRowMatrix().rows.toDF()
    df_list.append(df)

big_df = reduce(unionAll, df_list)
big_df.write.mode('append').parquet('some_path')
```

I want to do that because the writing part takes time and therefore, it is much faster to write one big file than n small files in my case.

The problem is that when I write `big_df` and check Spark UI, I have way too many tasks for writing parquet. While my goal is to write ONE big dataframe, it actually writes all the sub-dataframes.

Any guess?

Comment: You should do a coalesce before writing if you want to get less/bigger part files but that won't reduce the number of tasks

Answer (score 0):

Spark is lazy evaluated. 
The `write` operation is the action that trigger all previous transformations. Therefore those tasks are for those transformations, not just for writing parquets.